# Following tutorial for installing Ruby on Rails for Heroku. Currently stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

very new to all this. I am following a tutorial to get Heroku running through ruby on rails.

I have Microsoft Windows so I am currently following Heroku's official tutorial and am [stuck here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-jruby#run-the-app-locally)

I installed PostgresSQL 10.1 using windows installer x86-64 and have noted my login information for Postgres.

However, I do not understand this part:

> Remember to update your `PATH` environment variable to add the bin
>   directory of your Postgres installation. The directory will be similar
>   to this: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<VERSION>\bin`. If you forget to
>   update your `PATH`, commands like `heroku pg:psql` won’t work.

The closest thing I could find to an explanation and tutorial was this [Java site.](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

I went inside Enviromental Variables and set the system path to: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin`

However, when I tried testing it out by typing in `heroku pg:psql`, it said no app specified so I'm unsure if I did it correctly or not.

Also, the next tutorial step is:

> Open the config\database.yml file and set the username and password
>   for your local (development) database. Look for these line:

I searched and I have no such file on my computers. Needless to say, I'm stumped. Any assistance to progress through the tutorial is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

regarding your first error, the problem is that you are not specifying for which app you want to open the database cli (psql). Hopefully, the solution is easy:

```
heroku pg:psql --app app_name
# or
heroku pg:psql -a app_name
```

About the second question, the tutorial assumes that you have already created an application.

If you go to the root path of your project, you will find some subfolders such as app, config, db, lib, public, tmp, vendor.. Here you will find `config\database.yml`.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my first problem. For the second one, I created a random application through command prompt ruby on rails but I can't find it in any of my folders? I can access it through the heroku site though. Is the folder suppose to be accessible from heroku's site because I can't find the root app anywhere on my computer.

Comment: If you can find it on Heroku but not locally then you might have just created it on Heroku only. If you created an app locally it would be in what ever folder you were in on the command line when you created it (run `pwd`).

Comment: I guess that your app is not really working on heroku it you just created one. You have now the app container. You should create now a new app locally `rails new app-name` and it will create the skeleton

Comment: The next step would be to add to your git remote an _heroku master_ branch as explained here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote